# Two Different results when querying ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#

I have a ConcurrentDictionary that hold `class` objects.
The ConcurrentDictionary is updated every 100 milliseconds give or take.. 
The Position object hold a function that called `CalcNet()` which return the sum.

When looping the ConcurrentDictionary values(which hold the Position objects) I'm getting two different results.

Each iteration use different method and gets different result.

1. `Relations.GetEnumerator()`
2. `Relations.Values.Sum(x => x.Net());`

Code:

```
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Position> _relations = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Position>();
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Position> Relations { get { return _relations; } private set { _relations = value; } }


    public decimal CalcNet()
    {
        decimal positive = 0;
        decimal negative = 0;            

        var enumerator = Relations.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var item = enumerator.Current.Value;
            var net = item.Net();
            if(net > 0)
                positive += net;
            else
                negative += net;
        }

        var lastNetCalc = (negative + positive);

        var testSum = Relations.Values.Sum(x => x.Net());
        if (lastNetCalc != testSum)
        {
            // why?   
        }

        return lastNetCalc;
    }
```

Why `if (lastNetCalc != testSum)`? 
Expected result should be the same.

Comment: What is `Position`? You may run into overflow issues if you sure what there were no changes between first and latter calculations.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking.  You are comparing some values that we don't know about against some limit (30) that you don't explain, and then asking us why you are doing this?  Can you add some clarification on what exactly you're asking please?

Comment: Why aren't `Positive` and `Negative` local variables? Could another thread be modifying them while `CalcNet()` is running?

Comment: *Expected result should be pretty much the same* What makes you think that? In the time it takes between the two version of the same calculation, the contents of the dictionary could have changed. Also calling the `CalcNet` method multiple times will cause trouble due to `Positive` and `Negative` being shared.

Comment: @ LordWilmore I updated the post. can you look again?

Comment: @Sinatr  `Position` is a class object.

Comment: If it is updated every 100ms than it would change while the calculation is performed? Than why would you expect the result to be the same?

Comment: Why the rating if the post is -1? Don’t just vote.. tell me why and I’ll fix it

Answer (score 0):

How often your application has true for  `lastNetCalc != testSum` condition ? 
It might be:

```
  //while loop is ended
  var lastNetCalc = (negative + positive);
  //new value is added to dictionary
  var testSum = Relations.Values.Sum(x => x.Net());
  //lastNetCalc  is not equal testSum for this case
```

Could you provide definition of Net() method ? Might it change inner state of Position class like that?

```
        private decimal _n = 0;
        public decimal Net()
        {
            return ++_n;
        }
```

Comment: The diff between the arguments is to big, even with the constant moving